# Optimize code to filter R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some R code that takes in the args string from the command line and then filters a dataframe based on values in a column; the args string contains the column names. Right now I'm doing it by looping through the vector but something tells me that there has to be a better way. Is there a way to optimize this code?

```
args = c("col1","col2")
for(i in args){
  df = df[df[,i]==0,]
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Can you give some example values and intended output? Do you get what you expect with your existing code?

Comment: So you only want the rows where either column is zero? `df <- df[ df[[args[1] ]]==0] | df[[args[2] ]]==0, ]`, this is a single pass through `[.data.frame` after building two logical vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep the rows where all of the `args` are equal to 0 (or any other given value).

First get the indices of the columns you're interested in:

```
idx <- match(args, colnames(df))
```

Then you can simply do:

```
df <- df[apply(df[, idx], 1, function(x) all(x == 0)), ]
```

Another possibility:

```
df <- df[rowSums(df[, idx] != 0) == 0, ]
```